# Algorithm for searching the combination with lowest price

Tags: algorithm, combinations, minimization

I have a set a products (a shopping cart), and a set of discount/offers to be applied over the products of the user shopping cart, but it is also possible that a product inside a cart fits into more than one offer. I'm trying to find an algorithm that choose, over a set of products, which discount/offers to apply and over which products. For example: a shopping cart that consists of 5 products with the following base prices:

```
p1: 6€
p2: 6€
p3: 9€
p4: 8€
p5: 12€
```

And the following discount/offers:

```
(p1, p5):     18€ => 10€   (you save 8€, or a 44.44%)
(p1, p2):     12€ => 9€    (you save 3€, or a 25%)
(p2, p3, p4): 23€ => 21€   (you save 2€, or a 8.70%)
p3:           9€ => 8€   (you save 1€, or a 11.00%)
```

And of course, if you apply the offer (p1, p5), you cannot choose the (p1, p2) offer, because p1 is then repeated, or the (p3, p4, p5) and the p3 discounts. The algorithm I'm searching for is the set of offers to choose to save the maximum amount of money with the restriction that no product can get more than one discount/offer.

An approach is to start with the offer that saves the most, and choose, in that order, the offers that doesn't add more than once any product:

```
(1) Choose (p1, p5): 10€
    Reject (p1, p2): p1 repeated
(2) Choose (p2, p3, p4): 21€
    Reject p3: repeated
    Reject p2: repeated
    Reject p4: repeated
End: we already have p1, p2, p3, p4 and p5
Total: 31€
```

Other approach is to start with the offer that saves "proportionally" (respect to the combined base price) more money:

```
(1) Choose (p1, p5): 10€
    Reject (p1, p2): p1 repeated
(2) Choose p3: 8€
    Reject (p2, p3, p4): p3 repeated
(3) Choose p2: 6€
(4) Choose p4: 8€
End: we already have p1, p2, p3, p4 and p5
Total: 32€
```

In this specific case, the "saving more money" wins, but I have got counterexamples where the "proportional saving" wins. I've tried even with  "proportional saving" respect to the cart base price.

What is the best algorithm in this case?

**NOTE:** Preferred language to illustrate your solution, pseudocode or C++.

**NOTE:** The linked "duplicated problem" has no solution to the question. Even though, the formulation is far different (I have not yet fully understand the linked question).

Comment: Rather than thinking of it as maximizing savings think of it as minimizing cost. You can extend the "deals" so that each item also has a 1-item offer that saves nothing. Then the problem is that you have a family of subsets whose union is  given set, and each of these subsets have an associated cost and your goal is to find a minimum cost partition of the set, where the partition cells are drawn from the sets. It is easily formulated as an integer programming problem, hence solved by such tools.

Comment: @JohnColeman The problem is the size of the set of possible combinations. There's should be an algorithm to "sort" the offers and base prices, in a way that can be traverse linearly, as I have tried to do (similar to minimum path finding or eager algorithms).

Comment: I think it could be a problem of the family of: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem

Comment: The problem is almost certainly NP-hard, although these sorts of problems tend to have pseudo-polynomial solutions which can be found by dynamic programming approaches.

Comment: The problem seems like it can be thought of as a weighted set packing problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_packing